# MVC Bootstrap Themes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-identity, owin

I want to include theme support for the bootswatch themes in my MVC 5 app.

I want the users theme to be saved and loaded when they log in.

I have extended my user class to include the theme and can successfully set and save a theme on the edit user page.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{       
public string BootstrapTheme {get;set;}
}
```

In the BootstrapTheme property I'll save the href attribute for the bootstrap css link. eg  `"~/Content/bootstrap.flatly.min.css"`

The plan is to set the theme in the layout page.

`<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.spacelab.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

How can I do this without querying the database on every page load?

Being able to do something like `<link href="@User.BootstrapTheme" rel="stylesheet" />` would be ideal.

Here is a link on how to save it for one page using localstorage http://wdtz.org/bootswatch-theme-selector.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should store theme name/url as a claim on the user, not as part of the `User` class:

```
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("MyApp:ThemeUrl", "~/Content/bootstrap.flatly.min.css"));
```

When user is logged in, this claim is added to the cookie and you can access it through extension method:

```
public static String GetThemeUrl(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var themeClaim = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "MyApp:ThemeUrl");
    if (themeClaim != null)
    {
        return themeClaim.Value;
    }
    // return default theme url if no claim is set
    return "path/to/default/theme";
}
```

and in your view you would access theme url like this:

```
<link href="@ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetThemeUrl()" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Claims on principal are available in the cookie, so no extra DB hits required.

As an alternative you can persist user `BootstrapTheme` as you already have done, but when user is logging in, add this theme as a claim to the identity:

```
public async Task SignInAsync(IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager, ApplicationUser applicationUser, bool isPersistent)
{
    authenticationManager.SignOut(
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    var identity = await this.CreateIdentityAsync(applicationUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("MyApp:ThemeUrl", applicationUser.BootstrapTheme));

    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

And then access the claim in the view via above-mentioned extension method. I've [blogged recently](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/08/aspnet-identity-and-owin-who-is-who/) about similar scenario - you can have a look there for a bit more insight how claims work.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look into claims based auth. I've avoided it until now because of our SharePoint division moaning about it for 2 years :)

Comment: I've recently converted 2 mvc projects into AspNet Identity and started using claims - the code is so much better and easier to maintain! And performance is increased as well - less calls to DB!

Comment: Worked Like a charm.

Comment: One thing to note is we need to add "@using System.Security.Claims" in the Razor view. (ASP.Net MVC 5 project)