# MVC User.Identity.Name with first and last names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-identity

I have added First and Last name to the `ApplicationUser` Class.

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

also added information to `RegisterViewModel`

My application successfully created First and `LastName` to the table but I am unable to get the first and last names as to display in `_LoginPartial`  "User.Identity.Name"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your partialview `_LoginPartial.cshtml`

Add the code:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
...
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext` = your DBContext -> Default : `ApplicationDbContext`

With the instance of `ApplicationUser (user)` you can get `First-` and `LastName`-property

Replace `User.Identity.Name` with `user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName` like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes that is , but the "User.Identity" doesn't seems to have the information

Comment: Did you add the properties Firstname and Lastname in the AccountViewModels.cs ?

Comment: this is added to  "public class RegisterViewModel" and this created the data in the table

Comment: -1. This would not work. `User.Identity` is of type `IIdentity` and it does not have method `GetName()`

Comment: trailmax: right.. i coudn't test my answer.. i have corrected my answer

Comment: @EdiG. Yes, this will work. But beware, on every request this will cause extra calls to the database which can be avoided. And if we are talking 1M users in the table, this extra call will bring the application to the halt.

Comment: This works well, of note is that I had to add some using statements for it to know what all this stuff was: using MyApp.Models
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add names as a Claim on user when user is logged in. Then in your views access these claims from `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims`. Have a look on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25384929/809357) that does pretty much the same, only you need to add names instead of theme.