# Want to get FirstName from database is spite of UserName in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display User `FirstName` from database when user logs on. Currently It displays `UserName` which is `email Id`. In `Account Controller`, I have written this code to get User `FirstName` from database based on User Login.

In `Account Controller`:

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
                    AdvertiserDBEntities ade = new AdvertiserDBEntities();
                          string username = ade.UserInfoes
                          .Single(x => x.UserName == model.Email)
                          .FirstName
                          .ToString();
                    ViewBag.FirstName = username;
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

In partial view `_LoginPartial`:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + (string)ViewBag.FirstName + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

But I am not getting the name which I passed it from Account Controller. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25643319/2218697) post.

Comment: @stom, It is showing error `ApplicationUser` could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting so your ViewBag is lost. You could store a user object in session or use TempData:

```
TempData["UserFirstName"] = username;
```

Then:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + TempData["UserFirstName"] + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

See [here](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications/)