# Storing often used user info in claim with Identity 2.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Building an mvc site using Identity 2.1 and a custom user model. There's some info in the user model that I need in almost every controller. Calling `FindByNameAsync` each time hits the db more than I think necessary.

If there are a few small `strings` and/or `int`'s that I need often, is the best idea to add them as claims to the identity when the person logs in?
`identity.AddClaim(new Claim("MyInfo", "xyz"));`

Or is there a more accepted practice, such as caching the user object in redis (or equivalent)?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the point of claims :)

Comment: @AshleyMedway how do I get the claims from User? User.Identity? Any pointer would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28138594/809357

Comment: @trailmax Ah, casting User as ClaimsPrincipal was the key. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Wavel, today store some user information that you need access this info faster, is very recommended to store it into identity claims, is best practices. But, it's not recommended that you stores any information or long information into identity claims, 'cause this identity claims infos are stored into the cookies after user login into the application.